# C# / WPF Bind in TabControl ItemsSource to property in code behind of List item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, code-behind

In my ViewModel I have a BindingList which holds my Views that should be displayed as tabs in my TabControl. The text for the tab is defined in the code behind of the view. I also defined a simple test class to test the binding which works perfectly. Only the binding to the code behind property does not work.

Xaml code for my TabControl:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabControlContentList}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName, FallbackValue=FallbackValue}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

The BindingList which it is bound to:

```
void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

public BindingList<object> TabControlContentList
{
    get => tabControlContentList;
    set
    {
        tabControlContentList = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
private BindingList<object> tabControlContentList = new BindingList<object>();
```

Test class:

```
class ControlTest
{
    public string DisplayName { get; private set; } = "";

    public ControlTest(string name) => DisplayName = name;
}
```

Xaml code behind of AnalysisView.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class AnalysisView
{
    public string DisplayName { get; private set; } = "Analysis";

    public AnalysisView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

In my ViewModel I have the following code:

```
public AnalysisView analysisView = new AnalysisView();
```

```
TabControlContentList.Clear();
TabControlContentList.Add(new ControlTest("Menu 1"));
TabControlContentList.Add(new ControlTest("Menu 2"));
TabControlContentList.Add(analysisView);
TabControlContentList.Add(new ControlTest("Menu 3"));
TabControlContentList.Add(new ControlTest("Menu 4"));
```

My TabControl then shows five tabs. First two have the text "Menu 1" and "Menu 2" on them, the third one reads "FallbackValue", followed by "Menu 3" and "Menu 4".

I have no idea anymore why the binding on the property in code behind in AnalysisView.xaml.cs does not work. Is this maybe a general Wpf thing?

Comment: There's few things wrong here. First, you don't need to (actually, shouldn't) have an instance of your `View` in your `ViewModel`. The whole point of having two different classes for those two and using binding is to decouple them and eliminate dependency. By doing what you're doing, you're adding dependency.

Comment: Next, having a `List<object>` is not a good idea as this can lead to many type problems as you're facing here.

Comment: @DavidP: What type does `AnalysisView` inherit from?

Answer (score 0):

Before I present my answer, I highly recommend that you download and learn how to use [Snoop for WPF](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf), or use the Visual Studio built-in XAML runtime inspection tools. These allow you to look at bindings, data context, etc.

The main reason why your code doesn't work, is that a `UserControl` doesn't have a `DataContext` by default.

So, updating your `AnalysisView` like so will give it a `DataContext` pointing to itself:

```
public AnalysisView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

However, the `DataContext` in a `UserControl` won't flow into your DataTemplate like your other objects. To make it work, you need to change your binding like so:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.DisplayName, FallbackValue=ERROR!, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Working with `UserControl`s like this feels like a hack. So you might want to look for ways to design whatever app you're building a little differently.

Also, the code in your sample is not using INotifyPropertyChanged for properties, so you won't be getting any change notifications. You might want to learn more about the MVVM pattern.